# Which Mac/PC text editing programs have YAML syntax support?

Tags: windows, mac, syntax-highlighting

I write/edit a lot of YAML syntax files, and syntax highlighting really helps determine where I have syntax errors in a YAML file.

Recently I've added two contributors who are not too familiar with computer programming, so it's important they have syntax highlighting to figure out where the errors are. I know Vim and TextMate support it but do other sites support YAML syntax highlighting as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Vim and TextMate...

The following have Yaml modes.

- Emacs has a [yaml-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/YamlMode)
- Notepad++
- UltraEdit
- Sublimetext

There are probably more, but these are the ones I know support YAML off the top of my head.